# I need to understand the use of TextFrame/TextFrame2, TextRange/TextRange2, etc. in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am writing some VBA for Powerpoint to generate slides from a series of short, coded strings.  (The slides are used for teaching games, the strings are sequences of game plays.)  I seems I need to use of TextFrame/TextFrame2, TextRange/TextRange2, etc. in Powerpoint VBA and am getting a lot of errors because the relevant properties cannot be found.  Is there a good general explanation anywhere of how these pairs of objects should be used relative to one another?  It does seem that some of the documentation online is inaccurate but often on very close reading it's actually just missing details of precedent conditions which would be known only if you had relevant experience.

Specifically - I need to change kernelling, indentation, tab settings and line spacing of text within a rectangle shape.  Sometimes .TextFrame2.TextRange works, sometimes it seems to be .TextFrame.TextRange2..

One specific example: It seems I need to use TextFrame to set the color of characters but TextFrame2 to set the spacing.  Sample Code:

pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
pptShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Spacing = -1

For readability I would normally have With statements to remove the qualification and leave the code containing just the relevant properties.

Comment: The online docs have good coverage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange2   If you're having a problem with something specific then maybe ask about that.

Comment: The commands without numbers are legacy commands that are kept for backward compatibility. The ones with numbers are newer versions with new properties and methods. Unless you expect to run your macros in old versions of PowerPoint, use the new commands. Using TextFrame2 for text frame operations and TextFrame/TextRange2 for text range commands should work.

Comment: Hint: While Powerpoint has no Macro-Recorder, but Excel has. Just place a shape on an Excel sheet, Record a macro and do the text manipulation you want. Look at the generated code - it should give you a hint how things are done, and it should work also in Powerpoint.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems some of the problems arose from using TextFrame2.TextRange2.  When I don't do that, the code is uglier but works.